# Feedback in hybrid power supply

Tags: power-supply, buck, feedback, negative

During my research of PSU I came across schematic from Linear's datasheet:

[image: http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3081fc.pdf]

1) Whats the purpose of node which is going from output to SW pin of buck converter?

2) Is node which provides 6V headroom for LDO sufficient for normal operation of PSU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The two Schottky diodes and capacitors form a charge pump that generates a negative voltage. With the 1K and 2N3904 they form a current sink that allows the output to go right to 0V with the 500K rheostat set to 0.

2) The dropout voltage of the regulator is on the datasheet. It is less than 6V.

Comment: Ad1) That means I cannot reach 0V out without charge pump and CB? Why just simply putting rheostat to 0 Ohm is insufficient?

Comment: There is a minimum output load current of 5mA specified in the datasheet in several places. If you want it to go to 0V you must pull the output towards negative voltage with at least 5mA at 36V in and high temperature. This method (the current varies with input voltage) is probably a bit more efficient than a fixed 5mA on the output. Without that circuit it would only go down to something like 700mV (see the residual output voltage curve). This kind of regulator feeds the quiescent current out of the output for greater efficiency (but at no load there has to be somewhere for it to go).